# jquery isotope uncaught error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

on my wordpress theme i have a isotope portfolio in which i can call the category through the url.

on the home page the error can be seen using chrome dev tools, this error is causing one of my plugins to not work but on any other page there is no error and the plugin works fine.

i have tried many fixes to make this work but hit a brick wall.

does anyone have any insight on this.

i have provided the links to be seen

Homepage ( not working with error): 
http://creativemotives.ddns.net:9999/~reidy/

Other page ( working fine no errors):
http://creativemotives.ddns.net:9999/~reidy/projects/#filter=*

the plugin is the scrolling ticker on the projects page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the page source

you ~reidy does not have

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://creativemotives.ddns.net:9999/~reidy/wp-content/themes/reidy/js/jquery.isotope.min.js?ver=4.3.1'></script>
```

Whereas the projects page does

Comment: added and nothing, no change

Comment: on the projects page I found 'Isotopes' 29 times but just once in the main page. Is the content loading properly on the main page? The scrolling ticket seems to be bxSlider.

Comment: thats because the portfolio in the page is tagged with the value to sort.

Comment: if your able to save a copy of the homepage and remove the nav bar it will work

Comment: yes, it does work when the nav is taken off the page, still checking

Comment: thanks, it must have you wondering what the hell is causing it lol

Comment: yep, :) and I narrowed down to the projects menus to be cause, If you just remove the projects menu, it loads well. trying to figure out why JQuery is reporting syntax error for those links

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93112/discussion-between-eli-and-lucky-chingi).